# Не срабатывает переключение с disabled true на false

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь реализовать сделать так, чтобы пока поле текста не заполнено, кнопка Start была недоступна. Однако даже когда вводишь текст параметр disabled остается true.

```js
function toggleButton() {
  let username = document.getElementById('username').value;

  if (username) {
    document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="welcomeForm">
  <div class="hint">Please, enter your username here</div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" onchange="toggleButton()" required autofocus>
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton" disabled>Start</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает. Просто, чтобы отработало конкретно это событие - надо убирать фокус с инпута. Это неудобно, конечно, но тем не менее. Поэтому проще заменить событие с `onchange` на `oninput`